# Cannot find a tag with JSsoup even though the tag exists in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, web-crawler

I've been experimenting with web scraping and wanted to try to do so with Node JS.  I have some experience with web scraping in python using the requests module and BeautifulSoup4, and I wanted to recreate my code in Node JS.  However, when basically mirroring my code (except changing some things to account for the difference in syntax) I cannot find the html tag I am looking for.  I use JSsoup with Node JS since it is the closest thing I could find to BeautifulSoup.  Here is my code so far:

```
const request = require('request');
var jssoup = require('jssoup').default;

const options = {
  url: 'https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/nkaj7292-002.xml',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
  }
};
function getVariant(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var soup = new jssoup(body);
      var nametag = soup.find('title');
      var product = nametag.text;
      console.log(product);
      var sizetag = soup.find('title', { string:'9' });
      console.log(sizetag);
  }
}
request(options, getVariant);
```

The code ends up finding one tag correctly (`<title> Nike Zoom Vomero 5/ACW (Black/Reflect Silver/Anthracite) AT3152-001 </title>`) but returns 'undefined' for the second tag.  For reference, here is the tag it is trying to find: `<title>9</title>`

I have also tried using an = instead of a dictionary and using contents and name instead of string but no luck so far.  What am I doing wrong here?

I tried looking at the JSsoup documentation too but it does not have much on find().

Comment: From JSSoup page: "[Status](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jssoup#status): There's a lot of work need to be done."  That may be your answer right there.  The author is trying to mimic the python version's API.  Perhaps the feature you want is not available yet.  You can always [open an issue](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup/issues) on the JSSoup repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one can [see in the source](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup/blob/94af47ba9209f4ed9c4b372c3f5cbbebfa679653/lib/jssoup.js#L153), it is expecting that any `string` to be matched is provided as the 3rd argument to `.find`, thus:

```
let sizetag = soup.find('title', undefined, '9');
```

I agree with Scott Sauyet that opening an issue may be wise, especially for fixing the documentation

Answer (score 1):

To get the innerText of <targetElement> with `soup.find`, use:

```
<targetElement>.contents[0]._text
```

I was also trying to **scraping** html within *JSsoup* in *Node JS* and found out it returns an **object**:

```
SoupTag {
  name: 'time',                           // name refers tagname
  contents: [ SoupString {.               // contents is array
      parent: [Circular *2],
      previousElement: [Circular *2],
      nextElement: [SoupTag],
      _text: '22 hours ago'              // here's innerText       
    }],
  attrs: { class: 'post-last-modified-td' },
  hidden: false,
  builder: TreeBuilder {
    EMPTY_ELEMENT_TAGS: Set(24) {...} 
  }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
find_time = soup.find("time", "post-last-modified-td");
if (find_update != undefined) console.log("Updated", find_time.contents[0]._text);
```

It returns:

```
Updated 22 hours ago
```